# Using test spy to record REST requests and reponse

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, restify, spy

I am trying to use [sinon.spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies-api) to record calls

*beforeEach*:

```
// Get restify JSON clinet instance
// Using rewire 
// m_jsonClient is a private field
m_jsonClient =  myMod.__get__('m_jsonClient')
jsonClientGetSpy = sandbox.spy(m_jsonClient, 'get')
```

*it*:

```
 sut.FunctionThatCallsGetMethodOfJsonClient(,,,function (err, ..) {
    jsonClientGetSpy.getCall(0).args[0] // url , i.e. /customers/123
    jsonClientGetSpy.getCall(0).args[1] // Callback Function

    // How can I access arguments?
    // If myMod uses strict mode I got
    //    TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties 
    //    may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments
    //    objects for calls to them
    // Otherwise
    //    null
    jsonClientGetSpy.getCall(0).args[1].arguments
 })
```

Is there possible to access "return values" in callback if spied function is not sync?

Comment: As I mentioned the main application area of test spies is if you want to validate callbacks are executed with certain arguments. But I don't know how to solve this problem in this case.

Comment: Also I am not sure if test spies are good choice to "record" REST/HTTP requests if I want to use this information later in stubs.